# Anyone know of a Java reporting tools which has a web based visual report designer?

Tags: java, reporting

We're currently evaluating different Java reporting engines, and having a web-based ad-hoc report designer is a requirement.

We don't need anything too fancy, but we need users to be able to define a report with columns X, grouped by Y, sorted by Z, etc...
We've found that many of the open source tools do have graphical report designers, but the designers are typically not web based.  (For example, iReport from JasperReports seems to be an application, not a web tool)

Can anyone recommend a reporting tool which meets this web-based requirement?

Comment: I hope you get a good answer to this.

Comment: Ideally, they would define the report using the web based tools, and the report definition would be saved to the server.  They would then just run the report online and view it as HTML, or download it as XLS/PDF/etc.

Comment: Questions: 
Where do you want to store the reports? On the server or on the client's hard drive? 
Will you write the code for storage or would you want the designer to do it?
Do the end users need to be able to create reports from scratch? Will they know SQL? Can they access the entire database?
What kind of security/permissions features do you want? For example, can the users upload any report and any other user can see it? 
Any other requirements you have?
Does it need to be HTML only on the client-side? Is flash/silverlight/JavaFX/ClickOnce acceptable?
Does it have to be java on the server?

Comment: The reports would be stored on the server side, and downloaded by the user.  We would prefer the designer to have code for storage, but would be willing to write it ourselves if needed.  The users do need to be able to create reports from scratch, without SQL - we don't need all the functionality in SQL, we just need the user to pick their columns out of a list of ~100, and pick sorting/aggregation criteria.  For security/permission, we assume we would have to do development on our part to integrate this, but users would be able to choose to share their reports with others.

Comment: The client needs to be able to pick view the executed report on screen in HTML, but would also have to option to download it as PDF/XLS.  Flash/AJAX would be prefered, but we are willing to consider other technologies as well.  JAva on the server would be easiest for us to integrate, since the application is in java, but we would consider other technologies.   Really, I know we are looking for a lot, i'm just trying to see if there is an existing library that gets us most of the way there and we can implement the rest ourselves if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an good answer for you, AFAIK nothing is out there that would be this good. Only wizard-based stuff for now or VERY poor quality commercial products (maybe I'm missing something).
However, I'd love to speak with you offline, I think it could be mutually benneficial. Please email me at scott at willeke com

Comment: JS Reports looks promising: http://www.jsreports.com/examples/embedded-designer.html

Answer (score 7):

Apparently JasperServer is exactly that (see "Drag and drop ad hoc report building" - http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperserver).  Haven't used it myself though.

Comment: JasperReports is very good software, so presuamably the JasperServer would also be :)

Comment: have a very bad experience with jasper reports when it comes to integrated with Spring. it sucks

Comment: On the other hand, I have had no trouble using Jasper Reports with Spring. It works quite well.

Answer (score 4):

*(full disclosure: yes, i work for i-net software)*

Looks to me like our own [i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear) (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear) might work great.

- Can read Crystal Reports templates
- Supports any JDBC data source
- Has a web-based (and also Swing-based) ad hoc report creation tool
- ...as well as a full-fledged report designer and report server
- includes a report repository for storing reports
- free and fully functional offline [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) as well

Check out our [Ad Hoc demo](https://www.inetsoftware.de/external-services/remote/public/remote/) and tell us what you think.

Comment: can I use a java code to run the report design and fill it using a hashmap wich contains parameteres

Comment: The online demo link is now at https://reporting.inetsoftware.de/public/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) for [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) pages.
It's a good tool.